# How to paginate an array

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

It seems that the standard pagination component in CakePHP 3 only allows the pagination of database queries. How can I adjust/overwrite pagination in order to display pagination of an array of data?

Comment: Suggestion: Inherit the component, overload what you need. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **Collection** to manipulate array data
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html

> Cake\Collection\Collection::take(int $size, int $from)
>
> Whenever you want to take a slice of a collection use the take() function, it will create a new collection with at most the number of values you specify in the first argument, starting from the position passed in the second argument:
>
> `$topFive = $collection->take(5);
>   // Take 5 data from the collection starting from position 4
>   $nextTopFive = $collection->sortBy('age')->take(5, 4);`
>
> Positions are zero-based, therefore the first position number is 0.

Comment: This is an ideal solution for me! Thank you :-)